# Cross tab summarized fields showing fix values

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I am facing a very strange problem in Crystal Reports.
I am passing a value of dataset column(Stock) to cross tab summarize field but it is showing constant value 1. I have placed that field(Stock) in text object and it is giving right figure there. I can not figure out what is problem. Will somebody help me. I have been working on this for 16 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're accidentally using Count() aggregate function instead of Sum()?

Comment: I find the solution datatype of my column was varchar i changed it to float and now it is working fine.Thanks!